# How to tackle the jquery conflict in jquery mobile and jquery

Tags: jquery, mobile

I am doing a site to view in mobile and have used the mobile css and jquery for the effects.i have used the below code for styles and effects.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>css/jquery_01.css" /> 

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.2/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.2.min.js"></script>
```

In my site i have a portion for drawing so i have used the jquery

```
http://slot.pixelass.com/
```

But the jquery for drawing won't works when i include the above mobile jquery.I am not aware of `how to tackle jquery conflict` .

please somebody help any help will be appeciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: why not use only jquery mobile??

Comment: I have tried alot find a mobile jquery for the slot machine but i don't get it

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/experiments/api-viewer/docs/jQuery.noConflict/index.html this might help you

Comment: i need exact that slot jquery

Comment: I have n't got any error message slot jquery won't works when i includes the mobile jquery.

Comment: Can you include jq mobile on the linked site, or in another location, so that we can try and work out what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific jQuery function called `jQuery.noConflict()` to help remove any conflicts with other libraries. Here is a snippet from [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // This takes out the jQuery variable '$' from the global scope
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```